# How to generate the client from a WSDL file in .net?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a client from a WSDL file without using visual studio itself and didn't know what the best place was to start.

A customer needs to take this same file and generate a client for a PHP application and I wanted to prove the WSDL was valid by creating a client myself (outside of studio).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) is a commandline tool that comes with the Windows SDK. It creates a WCF client (C# code file plus configuration file, the elements of which can be placed in your web.config or app.config).

I'm fairly sure you can pass a UNC path to a WSDL rather than a URL.

Answer (score 1):

[wsdl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.71).aspx) is your freind.

Update after comment - is this what you mean?

```
wsdl /out:[localpath]/myProxyClass.cs http://localhost/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
```

Comment: I came across this early on but couldn't get it to work with a stand alone wsdl file.  Each example shown points to some http endpoint ... do you know if wsdl.exe can point to a file locally?

Comment: wsdl.exe /l:cs localfile.wsdl /out:FooClassServer.cs /n:mynamespace

Answer (score 1):

To take a WSDL to a code module use:

`wsdl /n:<Namespace> pathtowsdlfile`

Then we want to compile the dll with debug symbols, and a given filename.

Use:

`csc /t:library /debug /out:<DllFileName.dll> pathtosourcefile.cs`